# How to determine if a set represents a line, plane or hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, span

How do you approach a question that gives you a set and asked to determine if it represents a line, plane or hyperplane?

The Question:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0gscqur18kqg3ma/SpanningQuestion.PNG

From what I gather this appears to be a plane because there are 3 columns. What I find confusing is why there is a 4th row and how to justify if it is a plane or not. There is an empty matrix that asks to provide a basis.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this question is boiling down to ask the dimension of the span. Since there are 3 linearly independent vectors, their span will encompass a hyperplane. Since the vectors are already linearly independent, they should together form the basis.

Comment: do you how to pick the linearly independent vectors from the set of three vectors?